# How to list Kubernetes object shortcuts?

Tags: kubectl

What is the command to list all the shortcut equivalent of kubernetes objects? Such as `svc` for `service`, `po` for `pod` and XXX for `clusterolebinding`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubectl api-resources`

Saw this from the official docs

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#resource-types